# Cannot remove eventlistener

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a JS code for a TODO list.

I intend to delete a node and move it to a new location by deleting the node and changing the parent. Now after I change the parent I want to remove the event listener because I intend to use a revert button to change the parent as in initial case. How do I do it?

Initial body: HTML representation  of the JS code should look like this:

```
<div class="databox col s6 offset-s1 waves-effect">
    <p class="checkglyph1 checkglyph2">Task no 1</p>        
    <a>
        <i class="material-icons checkglyph checkglyph glyph1 checkglyph2 glyphcolor">check</i>
    </a>
</div>
```

I add an event listener to the  tag to move it to new parent '.side1'.But using removeeventlistener requires a mouse event and a function.I want the eventlistener to be removed.
JS

```js
// creates a glyph text to look like tick button
 // here glyph is the <i> tag I referred in the html given above
 var node1 = document.createTextNode("check");
 newa.appendChild(newglyph);
 
 newglyph.append(node1);
 newglyph.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            this.classList.toggle("checkglyph1");
            //removes the check glyph to replace it with replay glyph(I intend to use this replay button to move this task to initial parent)
            newglyph.removeChild(node1);
            var node2 = document.createTextNode("replay");

            this.append(node2);
            this.classList.add("returntomain");
            newpar.classList.toggle("checkglyph1");
         completedtasks.appendChild(newdiv);    
         console.log(newglyph);
     
            // console.log(i);
        });
```

Comment: To remove event listener you should extract click handler as separare function. Then in rrmoveEventListener you will be able to provide it by name

Answer (score 1):

If you put the eventHandler in a function, you'll be able to remove it.

```
function eventListner(event) {
        this.classList.toggle("checkglyph1");
        newglyph.removeChild(node1);
        var node2 = document.createTextNode("replay");

        this.append(node2);
        this.classList.add("returntomain");
        newpar.classList.toggle("checkglyph1");
        completedtasks.appendChild(newdiv);    
        console.log(newglyph);

};

var node1 = document.createTextNode("check");
newa.appendChild(newglyph); 
newglyph.append(node1);
newglyph.addEventListener('click', eventListener)
```

Then to remove it:
    `newglyph.removeEventListener('click', eventListener);`